# Badly designed csv file breaks values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have csv file that uses `tt` as separator. But in some edge cases that is broken because some values might end with `t`. I am using this Gem https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv to fetch csv data.

Example of broken data:

```
4909ttZSWttPrince RupertttCanadattCAttNorth Americatt54.3333tt-130.283
```

Outputs: (note the city and country values)

```
{:id=>4909, :code=>"ZSW", :city=>"Prince Ruper", :country=>"tCanada", :country_code=>"CA", :continent=>"North America", :coordinate_x=>54.3333, :coordinate_y=>-130.283}
```

Is there a way to tell csv reader that if word ends with t check if the next character starts with the capital, otherwise do not separate. (note the (tt)t repeat). This is my current code:

```
options = {
  :col_sep => 'tt',
  :headers_in_file => false,
  :user_provided_headers => [
    "id",
    "code",
    "city",
    "country",
    "country_code",
    "continent",
    "coordinate_x",
    "coordinate_y"
  ]
}
records = SmarterCSV.process(filename, options)
```

Comment: Wow, `tt` as a separator. This seems to be a really bad choice. There are so many words that include `tt`. Writing work arounds and hacks to support such a badly designed format feels like a waste of time to me. Is there the option to fix the format in the first place?

Comment: @spickermann I totally agree. I mean seriously why would ever anyone use `tt` as separator, where is logic in that, but I guess I just have to deal with it. This is the reason why I titled question as "Badly designed..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @mudasobwa answer I also found another solution in which I didn't have to change code too much. I replaced `:col_sep` value from `tt` into regex provided by @mudasobwa.

```
options = {
  :col_sep => /tt(?=[^t]|tt)/,
  :headers_in_file => false,
  :user_provided_headers => [
    "id",
    "code",
    "city",
    "country",
    "country_code",
    "continent",
    "coordinate_x",
    "coordinate_y"
  ]
}
records = SmarterCSV.process(filename, options)
```

Edition note: I have replace the regexp

```
  /tt(?=[^t])/
```

with

```
 /tt(?=[^t]|tt)/
```

to permit nil values.

Comment: Oh, cool, this smart gem is really smart :) I did not expect it will understand regexp as separator.

Comment: Really cool this one, but still you will have a problem with `nil` columns. Try to get `tttt` and it will only recognise as a separator the last couple of `t`  (I have edited your response with an improvement for this)

Comment: Is that for cases such as `valuettvaluettttvalue` ?

Comment: Yes. Of course, considering that we can't have a column description such as `attributes`, because it will recognise this word as `a` | `ributes`

Answer (score 3):

Smart gems seem to be too stupid here.

I would go with:

```
File.readlines('path/to/file').map do |line|
  line.split(/tt(?=[^t])/)
end
```

This will produce an array of arrays. Whether you want to have an output as provided by this “smart” gem:

```
File.readlines('path/to/file').map do |line|
  user_provided_headers.zip(line.split(/tt(?=[^t])/)).to_h
end
```

Voilà. The above works, assuming that the cell value can not begin with lowercase “t”.

*Sidenote*: I wonder how quick we become too experienced in “how to use the code written by someone else” and too lazy to simply write small codepieces ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you replace the separator string to another thing like `;`? 
Maybe sounds like extra work but it will save you a lot of time, and consists just in executing something like this:

```
 "HolattCatttHey".gsub(/(tt[A-Z])/) { |m| ";#{($1).sub('tt','')}"}
 => "Hola;Cat;Hey"
```

Once this, you can happily use your gem.

Comment: I really want to do that. I even have my own scripts that do this task for me, but sadly I am not allowed to change csv files.